# created and deleted a database on mysql slave host by mistake

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication

I have 2 hosts: server1 (master) and server2(slave).
By mistake I've created and dropped a database "test" on server2(slave).
If the cluster will switch the master to server2, will there be any issues?

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If the test database on the Master was never in use, then the slave won't care. As long as the slave is not a master to another server, then you are OK.

If the slave has binary logging enabled, the database will just get created and dropped and a record of it would be in the binary logs of the slave.

Besides a test database would not be in use in Production.